# objective c option not showing in doxygen

Tags: ios, objective-c, doxygen

I am trying to use Doxygen GUI for generating the documentations for my iPhone project. In that there is an option as "select programming language to optimize results for". In this option I can't find the Objective C option. When I run the oxygen, Its showing only empty HTML files.

Comment: check with this link: https://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/manual/starting.html

Comment: i try that way but i dont get the correct result the function format appear like c not objective c.plz help me to find it.

Comment: try with this post: http://objectivecc.blogspot.in/2012/12/how-to-set-up-doxygen-for-use-in-your.html